# change file table file stream data folder faces error The container can not be dropped

Tags: sql-server, filestream, filetable

I want to change file database file stream folder from Drive D to Drive F. I successfully transferred data to new folder but when I want to Remove old file stream folder I face this error:
**"The container can not be dropped because changes exist that require a log backup. Take a log backup and then retry the ALTER DATABASE operation."**
When I want to get transaction log, It encounter this error: you should enable filestream on this instance, while filestream is enabled.
This my code:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
REMOVE FILE MyDatabase_Files;  
GO
```

Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the message suggests, you need to [backup the transaction log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-a-transaction-log-sql-server) in order to move on to the next step. You can do this inside SSMS with a couple of clicks or, if you prefer writing SQL, you can do this:

```
BACKUP LOG MyDatabase  
   TO MyDatabase_TXN_log1;  
GO
```

Once this is completed the requisite `ALTER DATABASE` statements can be run before restarting the SQL Server instance

Comment: Thanks, But when I wanna get backup It raise this error: you should enable filestream on this instance  While filestream is already enable.